# TM1 9.5.2 Java API function for Integrated Login

Tags: windows-authentication, java, cognos-tm1

I am trying to connect to TM1 9.5.2 to read the data cubes in the normal login mode and it happens fine. However, when the TM1 server is configured for integrated login, the Java code could not connect to the API. In the API documentation for C, there is a separate function, `Tm1SystemServerConnectIntegratedLogin` to connect to the TM1 in integrated security mode. However, for Java, I could not find any such dedicated function.

Answer (score 1):

Based on looking at the .jar for the TM1 9.5.2 Java API there are only methods for connection via the classic and CAM methods. The corresponding method for Tm1SystemServerConnectIntegratedLogin is missing. You might check what is available in 10.2 upwards as the Java integration has been significantly enhanced.